# ruby regex match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord

For my ruby on rails project, I have a model called message which has a to field. I want to implement a wildcard search so that, for example, `%545` will bring up all messages ending with `545`, `545%` will bring up all numbers starting with `545`, `%545%` will bring up all messages including `545`.

I have a query like `Message.where("to like ?", str)` where `str` is the string to match, e.g. `%545, %545%, 545%`...etc.

Everything works but I'm concerned about SQL injection attack. So I want to do a regex matching for `str` so that it only allows `%` and numbers to pass through. So I want strings like `%545, %545%, 545%` to pass, but not `abc, %545a, a545%, %54a5%` to pass.

I've tried `str.scan(/.*?(\d+%)/)` but that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly using placeholders, so you are protected from SQL injection attacks already. Rails will escape any unsafe characters in the pattern; you don't need to take any further action.

If you still want to strip characters other than digits and `%`, you can use Ruby's `String#delete` method:

```
str.delete('^1-9%')
```

The `'^1-9%'` argument means "Delete every character that is not `1` to `9` or `%`". (n.b. you cannot use `\d` here, because `#delete` doesn't understand regular expression meta characters.)

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-delete.